# How to solve a system of two inequalities where one is quadratic and the other is linear?

Tags: inequality, quadratics

As I am self isolating as of now I am having to use a google meet for my maths lessons. As such, the quality is not the best and at some points illegible (Please see below). **Actual question is below the first blurry picture!**

[image: See Picture]

**Actual Question:**
As a result, since I have no idea how to solve double inequalities as it's my first time, could someone please work through this example question below (step by step please!).

Use set notation to describe the set of values of x for which:
$$
x^2 - 7x + 10 <0 \qquad \text{and}\qquad 3x+5<17
$$

**Query:**
I have tried googling this type of question but I keep getting joint inequalities such as
$$
-16 \leq 3x+5 \leq 20
$$

Are they the same compared to the question above?

Thank you and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you solve them individually for range of $x$?

Comment: Quick answer: Solve the inequalities individually, and then compare the results. Use set theory and your own logic to combine the answers.

Comment: Use set notation to describe the set of values of x for which: That's the original question @MathLover

Comment: @MattiP. When i did that I got x=5 or x=2 for the quadratic and for the linear I got x =4 
Please excuse the "=" I understand that they should be inequality signs but i don't know which one to use: x=5 or x= 2. The answer is 2<x<4 but i don't know why x =2 is used instead of 5?

Comment: How can you get two specific values of x for quadratic inequality? Also, your values of $x$ for linear is incorrect.

Comment: @MathLover I would factorise which would be (x-5)(x-2) so x =<5 and x>=2 if i am correct in that.
**Someone edited the equation. I originally took a screenshot and posted it. The original linear equation was 3x+5<17. Sorry for the confusion **

Comment: Yes that is correct but as it has to be $\lt 0$, you get a range $2 \lt x \lt 5$

Comment: Understood, Thanks for your assistance - its 4* not 5. Nonetheless I appreciate your explanation about x needing to <0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving $3x+5<17$ we have $x<4$.

Then $x^2-7x+10=(x-2)(x-5)<0$ is satisfied when $2<x<5$ (draw a sketch!).

But we know that $x<4$. Thus the required solution is $2<x<4$.

See examples [here](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/syslneq.htm) and [here](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/ineqquad.htm).

Comment: Someone edited the equation. I originally took a screenshot and posted it. The original linear equation was 3x+5<17. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Are the inequalities $x^2 - 7x + 10 <0 \qquad \text{and}\qquad 3x+7<17$ or have they changed?

Comment: It's 3x+5<17** Once again I apologise

Comment: It's fine. If you had $3x+5<17$, then subtract $5$ from both sides and divide by $3$ then you will have $3x<12$, so $x<4$ for this case. Since from the quadratic inequality we have $2<x<5$ (easy to see if you draw a sketch), the solution would be $2<x<4$.

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom once again. Could you please edit that into your answer? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited it.

Comment: The answer in set notation would be $x\in(2,4)$.

Comment: @AndrewChin Is that the same as {x:2<x<4}? Thanks

Comment: @Gravity098 Yes, it means the same thing.